# ks.test without reference sample

Tags: r

I'm trying to check that 2 samples follow the same unknown distribution using the ks.test function.
I have two datasets:

- the dataset A tells me the percentage of time a value has been observed in a given environment.
- the dataset B is basically a list of observed values in another environment.

My understanding is I need to pass two sample set of observed values, so I should (?) build a sample set from the dataset A where the values are present in a percentage as defined in dataset A.

Here is a code snippet to illustrate the idea. Please note the actual values in set_A and set_B are irrelevant, I'm just trying to have a structure that highlights the problem.

```
library(data.table)


# one sample set showing the percentage of time each value is observed in env A
value <- runif(10, 1, 99)
time_percent <- runif(10)
time_percent <- time_percent / sum(time_percent) * 100
set_A <- data.table(obs = round(value, 0), time_percent = round(time_percent, 0))

# a sample set of all observed values in env B
set_B = data.table(obs = runif(30, 1, 200))

# I want to check the set_B follows the same distribution as the set_A
# I generate a dummy sample where the number of times a value is present is the same percentage as the one defined in set_A
#set_C <- data.table(obs = set_A[, rep(obs, time_percent)])
set_C = data.table(obs = rep(set_A$obs, time = set_A$time_percent))


ks <- ks.test(set_B$obs, set_C$obs)

if (ks$p.value < 0.05) {
  print("the 2 samples don't follow the same distribution whatever it is")
} else {
  print("the 2 samples do follow the same distribution whatever it is")
}
```

And now my question: does that make sense?

Comment: I think it will not influence anything, because eventually KS test will use the cumulative probability rather than the frequency.

Comment: but given my set_A being (obs = (1, 2, 3), freq = (3, 2, 1), ks.test( (1, 2, 3), set_B) cannot be the same as ks.test( (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), set_B)

Comment: Ahhh I've made one mistake here. The Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic will not change but the p-value will change. I just checked the "Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test" part in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test and recalled that the p-value is calculated using Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic, the number of samples and the level. To verify this, you could check the D(which represents the statistic) and p-value aftering running `ks.test(rep(c(1, 2, 3),10), unlist(set_B))` and `ks.test(rep(c(1, 2, 3),5), unlist(set_B))`.

Comment: Thanks for trying and helping m Yuli, and I apologize if I'm unclear. In your example, table(rep(c(1, 2, 3),10)) the 3 elements (1, 2, 3) have the same frequency, in my example, they do not. I only know the percentage of time a single element appear. And I'm asking if it makes sense to generate a dummy sample set from those percentage, so my dummy sample would be rep(set_A$obs, times = set_A$time_percent)

Comment: I will amend the code snippet to try to clear the ambiguity

Comment: Hi @Will, sorry that I didn't explain clear. Actually, your explanation is very clear.The reason why I've used `ks.test(rep(c(1, 2, 3),10), unlist(set_B))` is to show a simplified case. To verify my opinion, you could try `ks <- ks.test(set_B$obs, rep(set_A$obs, times = set_A$time_percent*2))` and `ks <- ks.test(set_B$obs, rep(set_A$obs, times = set_A$time_percent))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244648/discussion-between-yuli-s-and-will).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, if we know the probability of dataset A and dataset B and we form a dummy data using dataset A, we can get a fixed Kolmogorov–Smirnov static. However, if we don't know the sample size, we can't get a fixed p-value for Kolmogorov–Smirnov test because it depends on the Kolmogorov–Smirnov static, the number of samples and the level.

To verify this, we could run and check the value D and p-value,

```
library(data.table)


# one sample set showing the percentage of time each value is observed in env A
value <- runif(10, 1, 99)
time_percent <- runif(10)
time_percent <- time_percent / sum(time_percent) * 100
set_A <- data.table(obs = round(value, 0), time_percent = round(time_percent, 0))

# a sample set of all observed values in env B
set_B = data.table(obs = runif(30, 1, 200))

# I want to check the set_B follows the same distribution as the set_A
# I generate a dummy sample where the number of times a value is present is the same percentage as the one defined in set_A
#set_C <- data.table(obs = set_A[, rep(obs, time_percent)])
set_C = data.table(obs = rep(set_A$obs, time = set_A$time_percent))

(ks_1 <- ks.test(set_B$obs, set_C$obs))
(ks_2 <- ks.test(rep(set_B$obs, 2), set_C$obs))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Yuli! Also, I kept digging and it might be the case that this code would solve the issue maybe: ```(ks_3 <- ks.test(set_B$obs, ecdf(set_C$obs)))```

Comment: From my point of view, if you want to calculate the value D, it's fine. But if you want the p-value, theoretically, this is not a good method. `ecdf()` calculates the empirical cumulative distribution function and it also ignores the sample size.

Comment: Hey Yuli, that is also my conclusion from your previous input. I just didn't find another way. Maybe i should post my original problem on crossvalidated...

Comment: @Will I suddenly realized that your case should satisfy the one-sample ks test for discrete distribution. As mentioned in the "Discrete and mixed null distribution" section of "Kolmogorov–Smirnov test" page in Wikipedia, you could try to use **KSgeneral** or **dgof** package. I assume they have sacrificed something to loose the constraint.

Comment: For **dgof** package, you could try `dgof::ks.test(set_B$obs, ecdf(set_C$obs))`. Note that it has some constraint: ["However, the ks.test function due to Arnold and Emerson (2011) only provides exact p values for sample sizes less than or equal to 30..."](https://openaccess.city.ac.uk/id/eprint/18541/8/Dimitrova%252C%20Kaishev%252C%20Tan%20%25282017%2529%20KSr1.pdf).

Comment: For **KSgeneral** package, you could try `KSgeneral::disc_ks_test(set_B$obs, ecdf(set_C$obs), exact = TRUE)`. From [this slide](https://insurancedatascience.org/downloads/London2018/Session2/Senren_Tan.pdf), it seems to be more suitable to large samples.

Comment: I've noticed that my first comment is wrong. The reason why you can't use `(ks_3 <- ks.test(set_B$obs, ecdf(set_C$obs)))` here is because `ks.test()` in **stats** package is only suitable for continuous distribution: ["Alternatively, y can be a character string naming a continuous (cumulative) distribution function, or such a function."](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.2/topics/ks.test). That's why I suggest you to use `ks.test()` in **KSgeneral** or **dgof** in the following comments.

Comment: The reason why I made such a mistake is because I've totally missed the one-sample KS test. Actually, if you have a continuous distribution, you could use `(ks_3 <- ks.test(set_B$obs, ecdf(set_C$obs)))`. And now `ks.test()` works as you are trying to compare one sample with a continuous distribution. Sorry for my mistake here.